# If given two groups $G_1,G_2$ of order $m$ and $n$ respectively then the direct product $G_{1}\times G_{2}$ has a subgroup of order $m$.

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

I'm trying to understand if this statement is false or true, I have tried understanding by an example.

For example if $G_1=(\{{\bar0},\bar1\},+_2),G_3=(\{{\bar0},\bar1,\bar2\},+_3)$ then the direct product of these two groups will be

$G_1\times G_2=\{(\bar0,\bar0),(\bar0,\bar1),(\bar0,\bar2),(\bar1,\bar0),(\bar1,\bar1),(\bar1,\bar2)\}$

I see that $o(G_1\times G_2)=o(G_1)\cdot o(G_2)=m\cdot n=6.$ Can I simply say that I take the group $\{{(\bar0,\bar0),(\bar0,\bar1)}\}$ under the addition modulo 2 and 3 respectively and the statement is true for this case ?

Also if this statement is true shouldn't it mean that it will always be true considering that $o(G_1\times G_2)=o(G_1)\cdot o(G_2)$ and there will always be a subgroup of order $m$?

Comment: Without actually doing any work apart from just glancing at it, I wonder whether $G_1 \times \{e_2\}$ is always a subgroup of $G_1 \times G_2$, given that $\{e_2\}$ is the identity of $G_2$?

Comment: @PrimeMover Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $$H=\{(g, e_{G_2})\mid g\in G_1\}.$$

> Use the one-step subgroup test. Clearly $H\subseteq G_1\times G_2$. Since $G_1$ is a group, its identity $e_{G_1}\in G_1$, so $(e_{G_1}, e_{G_2})\in H\neq \varnothing$. Let $x=(g_1, e_{G_2})$, $y=(g_2, e_{G_2})\in H.$ Then $$\begin{align}xy^{-1}&=(g_1, e_{G_2})(g_2, e_{G_2})^{-1}\\ &=(g_1, e_{G_2})(g_2^{-1}, e_{G_2})\\ &=(g_1g_2^{-1}, e_{G_2})\\ &\in H\end{align}$$ since $g_1g_2^{-1}\in G_1$ as $G_1$ is a group. Hence $H\le G_1\times G_2$. But clearly $\lvert H\rvert=\lvert G_1\rvert=m$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to see that $G_1 \cong G_1 \times \{e_{G_2}\}$ is a subgroup.

Note that the map
$$\phi: G_1 \to G_1 \times G_2: g \mapsto (g, , e_{G_2})$$
is a group morphism. Hence, $\text{Im}(\phi) = G_1 \times \{e_{G_2}\}$ is a subgroup of $G_1 \times G_2$ and this is the subgroup you are looking for.

Note moreover that $\phi$ is an injection, so one can even say that $G_1 \times G_2$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $G_1$.

Comment: Actually, you can't actually say $G_1$ is a subgroup of the product. It's not even a subset. All you can say is what you said in the previous sentence, which answers the question.

Comment: @EthanBolker Formally you are right, but in practise you will simply identify $G_1$ as a subset of $G_1 \times G_2$ whenever convenient.

Comment: True. But the "actually" suggests a literal interpretation.  You might better say "Actually, that means you can often treat $G_1$ as if it were a subset of the product, much as you think of the real line as being the $x$-axis in the coordinate plane."

Comment: I simply deleted the last line. Thanks for your comments.